# how to parse a query in Wordpress using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, html-parsing

The JS code below parses the `title` and `content` in category.php but I'm unable to parse the `conference_speaker_business` which is displayed using the PHP code.

Basically, I would like to parse and show `conference_speaker_business` too using JQuery JS code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.view-post', function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_post_by_ajax',
            'id': $(this).data('id'),
            'security': blog.security
        };
        $.post(blog.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            response = JSON.parse(response);
            $('#postModal h5#postModalLabel').text(response.title);
            $('#postModal .modal-body').html(response.content);
 
            var postModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('postModal'));
            postModal.show();
        });
    });
});
```

This is the PHP code that displays the output in single.php that I would like to integrate into the JQuery Parsing above along with the `title` and `content` in category.php

```
<?php $meta_print_value=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'conference_speaker_business',true);
echo($meta_print_value);
?>
```

How do I go about this?

Here's the `load_post_by_ajax` as requested:

```
function load_post_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('view_post', 'security');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'p' => $_POST['id'],
    );
    
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    $arr_response = array();
    if ($posts->have_posts()) {
        
        while($posts->have_posts()) {
            
            $posts->the_post();
            
            $arr_response = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'content' => get_the_content(),
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    
    echo json_encode($arr_response);
    
    wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_load_post_by_ajax', 'load_post_by_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_post_by_ajax', 'load_post_by_ajax_callback');
```

PS: I'm using this tutorial: https://artisansweb.net/load-dynamic-content-on-bootstrap-modal-in-wordpress/

Comment: show us the code of : `load_post_by_ajax`

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant I have added/updated the question with the code. Thank you.

Comment: in your loop add `conference_speaker_business` like this: `$arr_response = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'content' => get_the_content(),
                'conference_speaker_business'=> get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'conference_speaker_business',true)
            );`

Comment: My god!!! I have been at this for days and couldn't get it. Please post this as an answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop add `conference_speaker_business` like this:

```
$arr_response = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content(),
    'conference_speaker_business'=> get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'conference_speaker_business',true)
);
```

Now it will be available to your ajax `response` variable. Fetch data from it in the same way you did for others.